# what drawable folders are used for Amazon Appstore Tablets?

Tags: android, android-drawable, amazon-appstore

I am trying to build my app for Amazon App Store wanted to know which drawable folder does Amazon Tablets use?
most of the tablets have a screen size of 1280x800

```
drawable-large-hdpi
drawable-xlarge-hdpi
drawable-large-mdpi
drawable-xlarge-mdpi
```

Answer (score 0):

To help you target some of your designs for different types of devices, here are some numbers for typical screen widths:

```
320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).
480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).
```

[http://developer.android](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)  see link and  **Configuration examples** point in it may be at last point in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the screen size qualifiers in their documentation:
[Screen Layout and Resolution](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-tablets/app-development/01--screen-layout-and-resolution)